# How to show 2 channel Image or chnage it into 3 or one channel in OpenCv

Tags: opencv, transform, conventions

I am new to Open Cv, I want to transform the two images,
here are my images,Left image and right image.
[image]

[image]

here is my Code

```
cv::Mat transformMat = cv::estimateRigidTransform(leftImageMat, rightImageMat, true);
transform(leftImageMat, reconMat, transformMat);
```

but the problem is that reconMat is of 2 channel. so how can I show it in openCv or convert to 1 channel image as shown above right and left images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what `cv::transform()` does. The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#transform)
 states:

> Performs the matrix transformation of every array element.

This means that the numerical value of each element is transformed by the specified matrix.

It looks like you want a geometric transformation. This can be achieved using [`cv::warpAffine()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#warpaffine):

```
cv::Mat transformMat = cv::estimateRigidTransform(leftImageMat, rightImageMat, true);
cv::Mat output;
cv::Size dsize = leftImageMat.size();    //This specifies the output image size--change as needed
cv::warpAffine(leftImageMat, output, transformMat, dsize);
```

Comment: Hello Aurelius , do you know how will I rotate the image from the with respect to center using any function, if there is some rotation in images as we calculated from the estimate rigid transform.